# Extraer datos especificos de una tabla mysql teniendo en cuenta una tabla base

Tags: mysql

Buen dia, tengo un pequeño problema con el retorno de los datos en de la tabla usuarios en unión con la tabla contactos que se especifica a continuación.

Tabla usuarios:
[Imagen de tabla usuarios con datos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XPKX.png)

Tabla contactos:
[Imagen de tabla contactos con datos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWV0X.png)

La idea del caso es extraer los nombres de los usuarios que estén en la tabla contactos de acuerdo a un id de usuario dado (excluyendo el nombre del id de usuario dado) y también un filtro de estado de invitación en la tabla contactos. He intentado con esto pero me funciona el filtro de el estado de invitación, pero en el caso de los nombres solo me trae solo los nombres de los usuarios de la columna id_contacto y también incluyendo el nombre del id de usuario dado. En el ejemplo: **id de usuario dado = 4**

```
SELECT c.id_usuario, c.id_contacto, u.nombres, c.estado_invitacion
 FROM contactos c, usuarios u WHERE (c.id_usuario = 4 OR c.id_contacto = 4)
 AND estado_invitacion = 1 AND (c.id_contacto=u.id_usuario);
```

Devuelve lo siguiente:

[Datos devueltos por la consulta SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW2yU.png)

Quisiera saber que opciones tengo para resolver el caso, *Cabe destacar que soy algo novato en mysql :)* agradecería mucho una ayudita

Comment: Puedes intentar con un join , sirve para unir dos tablas https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Nicoll Mejia gracias por tu respuesta, pero la verdad quisiera concertar resultados por medio de una query, estoy un poco mal de tiempo, debo tener resultados para dentro de poco y he leido un poco acerca de join pero me cuesta entender, ya quizá en otra ocasión con más disponibilidad leeré acerca de join. Igualmente gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Más oe mnos así  `SELECT contactos.id_usuario, contactos.nombres, usuario.estado_invitacion
FROM contactos
INNER JOIN usuario
ON contactos.id_contacto=usuario.id_usuario WHERE contactos.id_usuario = 4 
 AND usuario.estado_invitacion = 1; `

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Jeje, pero la consulta solo me devolvió los usuarios coincidentes con el campo id_usuario y no de el campo id_contacto :(

Comment: Falta hacer la condición completa como la tienes en el ejemplo, asi tal vez te de, con el join

Comment: Sigo sin tener solución :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

de acuerdo como entendí tu caso, esta podría ser la solución que necesitas:

```
SELECT c.id_usuario, c.id_contacto, IF(u.id_usuario = 4, NULL,u.nombres)
 AS nombre_contacto_, IF(u1.id_usuario = 4, NULL, u1.nombres) AS nombre_contacto, c.estado_invitacion
FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN contactos c ON u.id_usuario=c.id_usuario
INNER JOIN usuarios u1 ON u1.id_usuario=c.id_contacto
WHERE (u.id_usuario = 4 OR u1.id_usuario = 4) AND c.estado_invitacion = 1;
```

De tal modo que devolverá solo los nombres que correspondan a la búsqueda según tu entidad `contactos`, sin incluir el nombre del atributo que filtraste y también con el atributo `estado_invitacion` validado en `1`

Comment: MUCHAR GRACIAS!! es justo lo que necesitaba jeje, estudiaré más el join, veo que es muy necesario :)